# Difference between two types of a super class instantiation in Java

Tags: java, object, jakarta-ee, instantiation, superclass

I have an abstract super class called `Document` and two child classes called `Magazine` and `Book`. What is the difference between :

`Document book = new Book();` and `Book book = new Book();`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Second link is proper duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is for example if you have any information about document only in the document class, like, say, price. By doing

```
Book book = new Book();
```

you won't be able to get the price of the book, so doing

```
Document book = new Book();
```

will give you additional information about your object. Note that price is not the best example. I only wanted to show you how the super-/subclass work.